# USB devices are not detected on xubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, usb, xubuntu

I have just installed xubuntu 18.04 on my new asus vivobook 14 laptop it has 256gb ssd and amd ryzen 3 processor. whenever I plug any usb devices like a mouse or pen-drive it does not get detected.
I ran `lsusb` command while the USB mouse was plugged in I got the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In order to get it detected I need to reboot the laptop or plug in the device before its booted.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in the USB devices.

Comment: I got no results as I plugged in the mouse the terminal remained the same.